# DatastoreNeedIndexException even after defining the index

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am baffled with a problem with my DataStore query on GAE java -- it always complain that I don't have a matching index, even though I have the exact index they suggested in my datastore-indexes.xml -- can something shed some light before I pull all my hair out?

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="Users" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="BILLING_ENABLED" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="EXPIRED" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="api" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="CREATION" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

My datastore-indexes.xml

```
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Users" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="BILLING_ENABLED" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="EXPIRED_DATE" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="EXPIRED" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="api" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="CREATION" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

My Query:

```
Query q = new Query("Users");
Filter filter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(new FilterPredicate("api", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
"val"), new FilterPredicate(EXPIRED, Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, Boolean.FALSE));
filter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(filter, new FilterPredicate("BILLING_ENABLED", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, Boolean.FALSE));
filter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(filter, new FilterPredicate("CREATION", Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, cal.getTime()));
```

If I understand correctly, I need indexes for "api", "EXPIRED", "BILLING_ENABLED", and "CREATION" since these are used in the query -- but is there anything else I need?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested query is a bit different from what you have. It has to match exactly in order for it to work. Just add the suggested one as an extra index as is, redeploy your app and then check from the **Datastore Indexes** section on the Dashboard of your application if it's there and has the status: **Serving**.

Comment: Thanks -- that was it! I thought having extra columns in the index is ok, but apparently it has to be exactly the same.