# Searching on arrays using Datastore Queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm interested in migrating from JDO queries to Datastore queries to make use of the AsyncDatastore API.

However, I'm unable to make the following query work in Datastore queries:

```
//JDO query (working correctly)
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM "
+ Tasks.class.getName()
+ " WHERE archivado==false & arrayUsers=="
+ user.getId()
+ " & taskDate != null & taskDate > best_before_limit "
+ "PARAMETERS Date best_before_limit "
+ "import java.util.Date");

List <Tasks> results= (List<Tasks>) pm.newQuery(query).execute(new Date());

//Datastore query (returning zero entities)

AsyncDatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getAsyncDatastoreService();
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query query = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("Tasks");

Filter userFilter = new FilterPredicate("arrayUsers", FilterOperator.EQUAL,user.getId()); 
Filter filterPendingTasks = new FilterPredicate("taskDate", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL , new Date()); 
Filter completeFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(filterPendingTasks,userFilter);

query.setFilter(completeFilter); 

List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Apart from the fact that I have to build my Task objects out of the Entities resulting from the query, these should be the same.
The problem is that the query must look up if the passed user id (user.getId()) is present in the array (arrayUsers). JDO does this without any issues, but no joy with Datastore queries so far.

Any ideas about what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your JDO query has `taskDate > best_before_limit` but your Datastore Filter has `FilterPredicate("taskDate", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL , new Date())` — is that correct?  Also your Datastore query doesn't filter on `archivado` — what indexes do you have?

Comment: That one is correct, as I have tried with other query that doesn't have to look into an array and works as intended.
I forgot to include the `archivado` filter, but it think it is not relevant for the issue I'm having (is just another filter to add to the CompositeFIlterOperator)

Comment: Your indexes [need to match your query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221414/datastoreneedindexexception-even-after-defining-the-index). Do you have any suggested indexes in your `appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml`?

Comment: afaik if the index didnt match, the jdo query wouldnt work either.

Comment: @ZigMandel yep - it depends whether the `archivado` filter is included or just ommitted from the code sample.

Comment: @ZigMandel @tx802 Yes, I have included the corresponding index for the query, and in the code the filter `archivado` is included.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by the users commenting, you use different properties in your datastore query. If you have such a query and you don't have EXACTLY the index for this, it won't work. Without seeing what indexes you have, I say this query looks good to me, so either you don't have data that returns there (unlikely, since your JDO query does it), or you're missing a filter.

In general, in datastore when querying for one of the values to equal something specific, you indeed would use something like this :

```
new Query("Widget").setFilter(new FilterPredicate("x", FilterOperator.EQUAL, 1))
```

Since you're using an equality filter, you won't get funky results (as you can see in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) (look for "Properties with multiple values can behave in surprising ways")).

Comment: After discussing this matter with support, we have arrived to the conclusion that there is no way to do this using Datastore Queries, as we would need some kind of "CONTAINS" operator, and this does not exist.

Comment: @CésarQuijano Unless I'm missing something, what you call "arrays" is just a repeated value propertie. In such a case, an equal will provide what you want. In the link I provided it shows how to do it and what to expect. Looking back into the java datastore docs, I can't see an "array" property, so I have to assume this is in fact a repeated value property. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to do this using Datastore Queries due to the lack of a "CONTAINS" operator or similar.

The alternative to keep using JDO (at least for this kind of queries).